# Positioning images based on detecting reference points within another image

Tags: android, image-processing, imageview, positioning

Let's say for example I have a bitmap image of a tree, and I want to position other images (such as bitmaps of apples) on the tree leaves.  Is there a way that I could put markers on the leaves... red dots for instance... and then and then programmatically place apple images centered on those dots?

As a very basic test, I have image with a white background with one red pixel in the center.  I'd like to calculate the coordinates of this red point, and then set an ImageView to be placed on those coordinates.

How might I go about this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  I've edited your question to try and capture what you mean a little better.  You can edit your questions as well, with the EDIT button...and also see the [history of who edited what](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23287730/revisions)

Answer (score 0):

It depends, where your 'red point' marker is. If it's in the center or in any specific point (like 2/3 of width, 1/3 of height), you can just divide layout width and height to get right coordinates.

In other cases it would be better to set white background and draw markers manually in overriden dispatchDraw method. In such case you would just know the coordinates of the marker.

Answer (score 0):

You want to position an image over the red dot, right?

I'm thinking of two different ways:

A-> You could make the red dot to be an ImageView itself, and then centering it by using [gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html) in order to transform it into another kind of image.

Or...

B-> Make a container that uses the white background with red dot as background resource. Then center it by using [gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html) too, and finally, positioning your image to the center of the container so it will be over the red dot.

No calculation is needed if you thing this could help.

Comment: Thank you for response. Red dot in center is just for example, it can be anywhere on image. For example i have image with tree and I need to positioning another images (apples) on tree leaves. I thought maybe there is a way, that I can put red points on leaves and then programmatically put apple images on them.

Comment: I see, and how about using [MotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html?[link] You can get coordinates with getX() and getY() methods. But it is pixel dependant I think, so you might need to do some calculations.

Comment: Yes. But I want to use it only for placement onStart. User don't need to touch screen for it. I will investigate this, maybe I can find something.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are the one putting the markers onto your bitmaps.

If that is the case, is there a really good reason why you would want to be trying to embed the markers as data in the bitmap itself?  That leads you to the problem of having to rediscover the locations.  This could be a fuzzy task...what if there is a red barn next to the tree?  Are you going to put an apple image on every red pixel making up the barn?

What you might actually want is to define a format which has a bitmap with no markers on it, and then a separate list of coordinates for where you want the apples to go.  That doesn't require discovery of any kind...you just ship the image along with the list and you are done.

There are some cases where there is no "place on the side" that you can put information, and you actually need it to go into the bitmap file.  If so, consider also that there are some hidden places you can put data in bitmaps... metadata like Exif:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format

So that's a middle-ground, where you can manage to get the list of points to "stow away" into the file containing the image without actually requiring the modification of the pixels.

If you find you are really stuck in a situation where you *must* put these coordinate specifications into the image data, then something a little bit more unique than a red dot would be easier to detect with certainty.  Maybe there's something you know about your images... for instance, that they are PNG files and do not have any transparency.  You could make transparent dots indicate substitution points.

The larger and weirder the pattern, the more rare it is...so if you know your objects being pasted are always going to be bigger than 3x3 you could come up with a very unusual 3x3 pixel imprint for your markers that would be unlikely to occur in nature.  Uncompressed in 24-bit color, a sufficiently random pattern would only happen 1/(2^24^9) by accident.  Small number; although compression would create more gray areas.

But greater point being: if you don't have a good reason to turn a simple problem into a complex image-recognition exercise, don't.  Just keep the list of points on the side somewhere so you don't have to hunt for them in the image.